# Renaissance type: what is the name of the long swash at the end of a line?

Tags: print-design, typography, terminology

In scans of early printed books which use an italic type, I've sometimes seen an alternate letter form used at the end of a line where some extra space needs to be filled up. This alternate form ends with a long baseline swash to fill up the extra space. I can't find an example of this from an actual book, but these alternate characters look like this "m" from a sample of Cancelleresca Bastarda:

[image: swash example]

Is there a more specific name for this type of swash, which is more for filling up space than for ornamentation, which can extend a long distance when necessary, and which sticks to the baseline more than a decorative swash would?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Terminal Swash

> Initial swashes should only be used at the beginning of a line or word, while terminal swashes work best at the end of a line or word.

[image]

Source [creativepro.com](https://creativepro.com/typetalk-choosing-and-using-swash-characters/)

[image]

[Matahati Script Font](https://www.behance.net/gallery/48589593/Matahati-Script-Font) from Behance